# Why did rsync halt with errors but not display them?

Tags: rsync, backup

I have a very large (> 18tb) backup operation over rsync that halted due to a misconfiguration.

The progress display locked up mid-print:

```
 289,792 100%    2.36MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#8494957, ir-chk=1000/8728267)
  216,064 100%    1.66MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#8494958, ir-chk=1000/8728269)
  355,328 100%    2.51MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#8494959, ir-chk=1000/8728271)
  592,896 100%    3.79MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#8494960, ir-chk=1000/8728273)
   27,648 100%  180.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#8494961, ir-chk=1000/8728275)
   68,608 100%  437.91kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#8494962, ir-chk=1000/8728277)
   52,224 100%  331.17kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#8494963, ir-chk=1000/8728279)
   32,768   8%  198.76kB/s    0:00:01
```

I can confirm that progress had stopped because all of the LEDs on the drives had stopped blinking.

I canceled the transfer with CTRL-C and got a long stream of error messages (truncated here):

```
rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(638) [sender=3.1.2]
rsync: set_acl: sys_acl_set_file(1394bus.pdb, ACL_TYPE_DEFAULT): Operation not supported (95)
rsync: set_acl: sys_acl_set_file(1394bus.pdb/38309E30BCE449E799658EFE3AD7F8FC1, ACL_TYPE_DEFAULT): Operation not supported (95)
rsync: set_acl: sys_acl_set_file(cmstplua.pdb, ACL_TYPE_DEFAULT): Operation not supported (95)
rsync: set_acl: sys_acl_set_file(cmstplua.pdb/601030F64B7443E1A6C613AA2878BD8F1, ACL_TYPE_DEFAULT): Operation not supported (95)
rsync: set_acl: sys_acl_set_file(1394ohci.pdb, ACL_TYPE_DEFAULT): Operation not supported (95)
rsync: set_acl: sys_acl_set_file(1394ohci.pdb/2EDA60FFED944F66B3E5F871910B89D31, ACL_TYPE_DEFAULT): Operation not supported (95)
```

The cause of this error was that I was copying from a drive mounted with posixacls to another one with noacls.

My question is, why did rsync copy SOME files but not others, why did it not continue copying files that it could do successfully, and why did it halt with errors but not display them?

I used the following options:

```
rsync -axHAWXS --numeric-ids --info=progress /a /b
```

This is a copy operation between two ZFS (OpenZFS) pools connected via SATA on CentOS 7.9.

Comment: Your target disks aren't shingled are they? It's a possible reason for the dramatic drop in speed, and subsequent apparent lock-up of the disk-bound `rsync`

Comment: They are not shingled.